# Не работает toggleClass jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Я пытаюсь добавить стиль css с помощью метода toggleClass,чтобы фон иконок изменялся, но это не срабатывает в моем случае, в чем проблема?

```js
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("label");
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
  inputs[i].addEventListener("click", myFunction);
}

function myFunction() {
  $("#" + this.id).toggleClass("check");
}
```

```css
div.button-set {
  display: inline-flex;
}

div.button-set>label {
  position: relative;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  border-radius: 100px;
}

.check {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="button-set">
  <label id="back" title="Почта"><img src='data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0idXRmLTgiPz4KPCEtLSBHZW5lcmF0b3I6IEFk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%0D%0ALTYuOCwwTDExMCwxMjcuNUw2NiwxNzYuOHoiLz4KPC9nPgo8L3N2Zz4K'><input class="radio" id="radio" type="radio" name="button-set" value="Почта" style="display:none;"></label>

  <label id="back1" title="WhatsApp"><img src='data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0idXRmLTgiPz4KPCEtLSBHZW5lcmF0b3I6IEFk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%0D%0APgo='><input class="radio" id="radio1" type="radio" name="button-set" value="WhatsApp" style="display:none;"></label>

  <label id="back2" title="Telegram"><img src='data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0idXRmLTgiPz4KPCEtLSBHZW5lcmF0b3I6IEFk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%0D%0Admc+Cg=='><input class="radio" id="radio2" type="radio" name="button-set" value="Telegram" style="display:none;"></label>

  <label id="back3" title="Viber"><img src='data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0idXRmLTgiPz4KPCEtLSBHZW5lcmF0b3I6IEFk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'><input class="radio" id="radio3" type="radio" name="button-set" value="Viber" style="display:none;"></label>

</div>
```

Comment: `function myFunction() { this.classList.toggle("check"); }`, а в jQuery - `$(this).toggleClass('check');` // Не работает, потому что label сам еще раз кликает и получается, что одним кликом кликается дважды. Легче всего будет поменять тег) Или привязать функцию не к клику, а радио-кнопке, `...listener('change', ....)`

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME спасибо,плохо читал, не знал о слушателе change, это действительно подходит

Comment: `console.dir( window )` - можно так смотреть все свойства объекта. Там событий штук 100+ ))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Советую использовать FontAwsome для иконок, а не картинки.

```js
var fab = $('.fab');

fab.on('click', function() {
 fab.removeClass('check');
  $(this).addClass('check');
});
```

```css
.fab {

font-size: 40px;
margin: 10px;
padding: 10px 13px;

  border: 1px black solid;
  border-radius: 100px;

}

.check {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.css">

<div class="button-set">
 <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>
  <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>
 <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>
 <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>


</div>
```